# applescript to compare cell values and then place the value of one cell into another

Tags: applescript, iwork

in a numbers app table i have the following data

```
   A          B                     C                 D
user_id     login                user_id        login
2039        Abbott, Rachael                     Adams, Sue
110         Abbott, Shelby                      Adamson, Wendy
2910        Abraham, Binu                       Anderson, Daryl
121         Adams, Sue
122         Adamson, Anne
126         Adamson, Wendy
```

i am trying to write an applescript that will...

1. iterate down logins in column D
2. to find a matching login in column B
3. take the value of the user_id in column A at the row where the match was found
4. and place it into column C in the same row as the entry in column D

> ```
> set dName to "correlationstudies.numbers"
> set sName to "users"
> set tName to "Table 1"
> set login_row to 2
> set login_w_id_row to 2
>
> tell application "Numbers" to tell document dName to tell sheet sName to tell table tName
>    repeat
>       set login to value of cell login_row of column 4
>       if login = "" then exit repeat
>       set login_w_id_row to 2
>
>       repeat
>          set logincomp to value of cell login_w_id_row of column 2
>          if logincomp = login then
>             set value of cell login_row of column 3 to value of cell login_w_id_row of column 1
>             exit repeat
>          end if
>          set login_w_id_row to login_w_id_row + 1
>       end repeat
>       set login_row to login_row + 1
>    end repeat
> end tell
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppleScript may be superfluous for what you're trying to do. In the numbers documentation, take a look at the VLOOKUP function, which is passed a value to look up, a set of cells to look up in, and the column of the value to return. I got it to work only by swapping the order of the user_id and login columns, but once I put the login in column A and the user_id in column B, setting cell C1=VLOOKUP(D2, A2:B7, 2 ) returned 121 successfully.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck. That is a great function. I will definitely use that in the future. In this case, i need to be able to delete the first two rows because there is so much data in the table and its eating up memory big time. If i can figure out how to copy and past the cell results without the formula, which you can do in Excel, then this method would definitely work next time i have to do this.

Comment: it seems that Excel's "paste special" is available in numbers as "paste values." No need to write a script in the future. Thanks.